# How can I change an already created list inside a for loop

Tags: python, list

I am trying to change some values of a list, which I have already populated, with other values inside a for loop but at the end the changes are not present outside of the loop, nor inside

```
for x in range(1,shiftDays):

    if len(morningIndex) > 2:
        print(morningIndex)
        for i in morningIndex:
            print("Begginning",i)
            print(masterPlan[i][x])
            if shiftChange["Employee{0}".format(i)] == True:
                if counter[x][1]<2:
                    masterPlan[i][x] == 'e'
                    counter[x][1] += 1
                    print("M-->E", masterPlan[i][x])
                else:
                    masterPlan[i][x] == 'v'
                    print("M-->V",masterPlan[i][x])
                shiftChange["Employee{0}".format(i)] = False
                changeHistory.update({"{0}".format(i):x})
                print("Shiftchange true",masterPlan[i][x])
            else:
                for i in morningIndex:
                    diff = x - changeHistory["{0}".format(i)]
                    if diff >= change[0]:
                        change[0] = diff
                        change[1] = y   
                masterPlan[change[1]][x] = 'v'
                changeHistory.update({"{0}".format(i):x})
                print("Shiftchange False",masterPlan[i][x])
            counter[x][0] -= 1
            print("End",masterPlan[i][x])
    morningIndex = []
    eveningIndex = []
```

The expected result is that within masterPlan the values change to whatever the if statement is, the actual result is that the list remains the same.

Comment: I would suggest you to provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now it is unnecessarily hard for the readers to spot any bug you may have in the code.

Comment: masterPlan is a list of lists

Comment: if you mean e.g. this line `masterPlan[i][x] == 'v'` you are doing a comparison `==`, what you probably want is an assignment e.g. `masterPlan[i][x] = 'v'` with `=` instead ot `==`.

Comment: I have been at it for days! how stupid!

Answer (score 0):

Just access a list item by its index:

```
ll = list(range(10))
print(ll)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        ll[i] = 'Bang!'

print(ll)
# ['Bang!', 1, 'Bang!', 3, 'Bang!', 5, 'Bang!', 7, 'Bang!', 9]
```

Comment: As you see from the code I am using the indexes to access the list inside the list and then assigning it to the new value, but this doesn't change the value

Comment: I am pretty sure this approach works for any nesting level of lists.

Comment: Yes it works but the problem was with the == instead of =. Thank you!!